# Knockout mapping - difference between objects and observables in class being mapped to

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is driving me absolutely insane, and I just cannot see what I have done wrong. Please help before I start bibbling and gnawing my colleagues leg off. He doesn't deserve that.

I have an object I am mapping, which has a property that can or cannot contain an object of that same type. That is the only level of nesting there is. It is very simple; it is complicated only by the fact that the object is calling a base class constructor to set some default behaviour.

This base class sets up all the fields that can appear in the model (it is a generated file) and then maps the datasource, if it has one.

The mapping of the nested field to the correct constructor works if the field is set up initially as an observable. It does not if it is set up as a plain object.

```
var NS = {};
var _itest = 0;

NS.FieldModelBase = function(data, mapping)
{
    var _this = this;

    this.Text = ko.observable();

    // DOES NOT WORK 
    this.AlternateField = {};       

    // WORKS
    //this.AlternateField = ko.observable();       

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, _this);
};

// =====================================================================
NS.FieldModel = function(data, mapping, parent)
{
    var _this = this;   

    window.console && console.log('CREATING FIELD', data); 

    var _mapping = $.extend({}, mapping, {
        'include': [ 'Test' ],
        'AlternateField': {
            create: 
                function(o) 
                { 
                    window.console && console.log('FOUND SUBFIELD', o.data);

                    return o.data ? new NS.FieldModel(o.data) : null;
                }
        }
    });

    this.Test = ko.observable(_itest++);

    NS.FieldModelBase.call(_this, data, _mapping);
}       

// =====================================================================
var model = new NS.FieldModel({
    Text: "Main option",
    AlternateField: {
        Text: "Alternate option",
        AlternateField: null
    }
}, { include: [ 'Test' ] });

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/whelkaholism/fkr0w98u/

So, when setup as an object, printing `model` out after running the code gives:

`{"Test":0,"Text":"Main option","AlternateField":{"Text":"Alternate option","AlternateField":null}}`

There is no `Test` property on the alternate field. If you check the console, what happens is that the mapping `create` is in fact called, but the `o.data` property is null.

Change to an observable, and the output is, as expected:

`{"Test":0,"Text":"Main option","AlternateField":{"Test":1,"Text":"Alternate option","AlternateField":null}}`

So, what is the mapping plugin doing here? It was my understanding that it would map everything in source data, regardless of the existence or type of any existing properties on the object?

EDIT: I have solved my immediate problem with this change:

```
NS.FieldModel = function(data, mapping, parent)
{
    var _this = this;   

    var _mapping = {
        copy: [ 'AlternateField' ]
    };

    NS.FieldModelBase.call(_this, data, _mapping);

    this.AlternateField = data.AlternateField ? new NS.FieldModel(data.AlternateField, null, _this) : null;
}
```

This manually creates the correct object type for the alternate field after the mapping. The `copy` directive in the mapping is absolutely required, or the newly created object has no properties mapped.

I don't now why this is, so I'm still looking for the answer on why the mapping plugin works differently depending on the content of pre-existing variables, because I despise having code that I don't know exactly why it works!

Comment: interesting ! tough it works if it is `undefined` or `null`  other than `{}` may be(guessing here) because it is empty object(no value) so plugin ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping plugin maps only values, not objects e.g.

```
"myString" => ko.observable("myString")
null => ko.observable(null)
{ myStringProperty: "myString" } => { myStringProperty: ko.observable("myString") }
{ myProperty: null } => { myPropery: ko.observable(null) }
{} => {}
```

Comment: Not sure how this relates to my problem, I'm afraid? The mapping plugin should call a custom create function if provided, which it does; the problem is that that function has different behaviour if the object has existing properties, depending on the contents of those properties. But if you could tie this a bit more in to my example I'd see if something like this is the problem!